# What Password to Use for 'Push to Create a Project'?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have an on-prem GitLab server hosted in docker.

I have a few local projects and I'm trying to push and create remote repos. I followed the GitLab documentations to 'push to create a project' (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html)

But when using `git push --set-upstream git@mydomain.com:namespace/nonexistent-project.git master`, I'm prompted to enter password for git@mydomain.com.

What password do I use here? I tried the admin password for GitLab server, password for my GitLab account and the passphrase for my SSH key, but none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

If Git defaults back to a *password*, that means the SSH portion of the `git push` did not find a suitable SSH key.

That happens if your SSH key is not the standard default ~/.ssh/id_rsa, but a dedicated ~/.ssh/mykey.

In that case, you need a ~/.ssh/config file with:

```
Host mygitlab
  Hostname mydomain.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey
```

The push becomes:

```
git push --set-upstream mygitlab:namespace/nonexistent-project.git master
```

If your private key is passphrase-protected, don't forget to `ssh-add` it first.